# How do i know if another window is closed?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qdialog

So, i need to update ComboBox in MainWindow after Another Window is closed. here's button's function to open another window

```
import AnotherWindow as cl

       def inputclass(self):
                self.InputClass = cl.InputWindow()
                self.InputClass.show()
                self.boxclass()

       def boxclass(self):
            self.BoxClass.clear()
            with open('data/ClassSuara.csv','rb') as f :
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                listsuara = list(reader)
            for a in listsuara:
                cek = str(a)
                b = cek[2:-2]
                self.BoxClass.addItem(b)
```

here AnotherWindow Window

```
class InputWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, gui.Ui_KelasSuara):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        gui.Ui_KelasSuara.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.BtnTambah.clicked.connect(self.Tambahkan)

    def Tambahkan(self):
        self.listClass.clear()
        ClassSuara = open('data/ClassSuara.csv','a')
        ClassSuara.write(self.lineClass.text()+'\n')
        ClassSuara.close()
```

But after AnotherWindow is closed, `self.boxclass()` wont execute

Comment: Please elaborate, your explanation it's really vague.

Comment: here you go @DiegoContreras

Comment: Why don't you just call the function before closing the window?

Comment: not working@DiegoContreras

Comment: where did you try to call the "boxclass" method? Aren't you forgeting .show? (not familiar with pyqt)

Comment: in AnotherWindow.Tambahkan, all i want is after 'BtnTambah' is clicked, the ComboBox in MainWindow upadated. nothing's wrong with .show @DiegoContreras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm,solved it by change AnotherWindow to QDialog, and change `self.InputClass.show()` to `self.InputClass.exec_()`